# PingPlacePicker no realiza búsquedas ni muestra los lugares cercanos / Android

Tags: android, google-places

Buen día, tengo un par de problemas con el mapa de Google utilizando `PingPlacePicker` en primer lugar simplemente no me muestra los lugares cercanos, cuando trato de buscar algún lugar el buscador se cierra y donde debería decir **"Elegir esta ubicación"** no me aparece nada, **cabe mencionar que tampoco me muestra la imagen al seleccionar el lugar**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La implementación la he seguido con una guía de GitHub:

https://github.com/rtchagas/pingplacepicker

Y a pesar de que lo he implementado tal y como esta en la guía no obtengo el mismo resultado, ¿Qué mas debo de hacer o porque no obtengo el resultado esperado?

Dentro de mi botón para abrir el mapa esto es lo que he implementado:

Libraria: `implementation 'com.github.rtchagas:pingplacepicker:2.0.6'`

```
PingPlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PingPlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
builder.setAndroidApiKey("com.google.android.geo.API_KEY")
.setMapsApiKey("AIzaSyCgc3KUTal8fImKlv4hSeiX6YMm0A69fUU");                         

try {
Intent placeIntent = builder.build(this);
startActivityForResult(placeIntent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Y así de simple es el código para abrir el mapa, claramente siento que falta algo pero a pesar de las investigaciones no obtengo una respuesta concisa de donde radica el problema, y eso seria todo espero que alguien me pueda hacer ver el problema de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Se muestra algún error en el LogCat?

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys no revisando el logcat no muestra ni un solo error o advertencia relacionada con el código o librería

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar el proyecto [Ping Place Picker](https://github.com/rtchagas/pingplacepicker) se hace uso de [Google Maps Platform Billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing)  y de Google Places API por lo tanto tienes que ir a https://console.cloud.google.com/apis y activar la API

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No olvides que cada llamada tiene un costo :-P :

> Google Places: búsqueda cercana (precio a partir de 0,032 USD por llamada)

Google Maps Platform Billing

https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#nearby-search

Comment: La API la tengo habilitada eso del costo por llamada obligatoriamente tengo que pagar para que me funcione? o hay alternativas?

Comment: Tienes cierta cantidad gratis para usar la API, pero sabes Adiel, te sugiero revisar en el LogCat ahí puede mostrarse no un error pero tal vez un aviso sobre el problema.

Comment: Hola, hasta el día de ahora he puesto tu respuesta como aceptada ya que tuve que investigar este tema de los precios y si efectivamente tenia que pagar un pequeño precio por cada servicio que utilice, ya sea búsqueda de lugares, lugares cercanos, información en la pantalla e imágenes, saludos!